# Incremental Singular Value Decomposition for OpenCV

Tags: opencv, eigen, pca, svd

I have a large archive of images from outdoor camera. Close to 200000 items, each 1280x960 color pixels. I would like to index this database by constructing SVD (Eigen-images) for this data and making reduced vectors of data (say 100-dimentional vector for every picture).

Loading all this data into RAM at once would require about 200GB of RAM.
Firstly, I don't have so much RAM.
Secondly, it won't scale much. So, I am looking for implementation of **incremental** singular vector decomposition that probably should exist for libraries like OpenCV or Eigen.

I don't want to reduce resolution before making SVD because I believe that small parts (resoluted far objects) may be important to me, but reducing resolution I just lost all high-frequency features.

**Upd:**

- I found that NN algorithms GHA or APEX could help here.
- Yet another algorithm:
  http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~mic/doc/skl-ip.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen an implementation using Eigen. But it doesn't seem that difficult to code the same method that scikit-learn uses for [incremental PCA](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/14031f6/sklearn/decomposition/incremental_pca.py#L15).

Comment: The algorithm is simple enough, that is why I expect that there could be ready implementations.

Comment: @0x2207 you're right, I guess it's just that no one has requested or attempted to contribute this algorithm to eigen or opencv. I think both are open to contributions from the community. You could try to do that.